# How do you set global environment variables for child tasks in Spring Cloud Dataflow using Stream - Task-Launcher

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a stream with an Http source, custom processor and Task-Launcher Spring Cloud Dataflow Stream

[image]

I have a composed task the gets called from the stream - task-launcher

[image]

I pass several properties in the stream processor to the task-launcher and to the child tasks for example the kubernetes pull policy which I want set to Always for all the child tasks, example...

```
"deploymentProps":{"deployer.*.kubernetes.imagePullPolicy","Always"}
```

Passing properties for pull policy and volumes/volumemounts works as expected

I also want to pass an environment variable to the child tasks for spring to pickup, I have tried the following that does not work...

```
deploymentProps":{"deployer.*.kubernetes.environment-variables":"SCDF_ACTIVE_PROFILE=prod"}
```

[image]
Does not seem to make it to the pod in kubernetes, is there another way to get environment variables to the child tasks or is there something wrong with this approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this format: `deployer.*.kubernetes.environment-variables=SCDF_ACTIVE_PROFILE=prod`.

There is a little more information about it here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_environment_variables

Comment: This initially looked like it worked however, after starting with a fresh database it no longer works, it only appears to work if we set each individual sub task with this property without the * . Strange behavior if you run a composed task manually with arguments/properties it stores those in the database and uses them on future executions. There should be a way to set global properties for all sub tasks...